# Ternary Operator And Addition Precedence

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Could some explain how the following works, given the precedence table here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Given:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define MY_CONSTANT 5.6

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const double calculatedValue = 4.4;
    const double myValue = MY_CONSTANT + 1 ? 4.4 : -4.4;

    printf("%f\n", myValue);
    return 1;
}
```

I expect

```
myValue == 10
```

I get

```
myValue == 4.4;
```

Comment: What's the problem? `?:` has lower precedence than `+` according to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const double myValue = MY_CONSTANT + 1 ? 4.4 : -4.4;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const double myValue = (MY_CONSTANT + 1) ? 4.4 : -4.4;
```

Because `?:` has lower precedance than `+` in C++ operator precedence table

Because `(MY_CONSTANT + 1)` evaluates to non-zero, myvalue is `4.4`.

To get `10` as output, you need explicit parenthesis to change the order of evaluation:

```
const double myValue = MY_CONSTANT + (1 ? 4.4 : -4.4);
//                                   ^              ^
```

Comment: @Gerstrong It was used for a example, in the actual code the conditional is based on a class property. Yes I had fixed my code before I posted, I was confused why I had to add the parenthesis.... even after looking at the precedence table!! Thanks for the "Oh duh" moment :)